# Subtraction broken in Visual Studio Code (always returns 10)

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am new to both Julia and Visual Studio.

whenever I try to subtract two numbers
i.e. `3 - 5` I get 10

I am however able to add a negative number

`3 + - 5` gives -2 as expected

The behavior also occurs with the .- and .+ operators. I thought there might be something wrong with my "-" character so I tried copying and pasting from the julia page on mathematical operators (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/) to no avail.

[image]

I was unable to find any one else with the same problem. The problem appears to be limited to Visual studio as subtraction still works fine when I run Julia in terminal.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.71.2 with the julialang 1.7.12 extension and Julia 1.8.1

EDIT-1:
If I copy and paste the code from Visual Studio Code into the julia terminal (not terminal in VSC) it works. However, if I run the code using `julia the-script.jl` in the terminal I still get 10 for any subtractions performed. I have also tested editing the script with nano and then running it and I am encountering the same problem.

EDIT3: As was pointed out by several responders the issue was not with VS code

[image]

Thank you for your help

Could someone explain where my code is breaking the function `-`?
I am unable to reliably break it so that I get 10 whenever I try and subtract, but I have been able to reproduce the error with the above script

```
# #make the neutral model that I have in R in julia and benchmark both models
# #imports
using Random



# #set the seed 
Random.seed!(125)




#set the initial arguments
num_sp_local = 10::Int64;
init_sp_abundance = 100::Int64;
mig_prob = 0.01::Float64;
#meta community is uniform
num_sp-meta = 10; #ERROR IS HERE - function redefined to be 10


#the number of time steps to run the sim for
time_steps = 100000;

for i = 1:50
    println(i - 35)
end
```

The error can be seen above `num_sp-meta = 10;` redefines the `-` function to be 10 irrespective of what is being subtracted.

Comment: I know nothing of Julia, but is it possible that someone redefined the `-` method to just return 10 and put that into some kind of global initialization file? Maybe as a prank?

Comment: This is the most likely reason. Please start Julia in a terminal `julia --startup-file=no` and check again.

Comment: I wish I am on my personal system alone in my office.... I solved it by downgrading VS code

Comment: Then check definitions of `-` with `methods(-)` and you should see if some non-standard thing is there (unfortunately in this case the list is long so probably it is easiest to compare the list in the problematic environment vs the list in an environment that works correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has *nothing* to do with VS Code, changing your editor/IDE is a pointless waste of time.

As @JoachimSauer suggested, someone (maybe you?) has re-defined the `-` function in your Julia instance.

- Try fixing `-` by resetting it to `Base.-` like this:  `-(x::Int, y::Int) = Base.:-(x, y)`
- That might not work, depending on how the change was originally done.
- Restart the REPL in VS Code. Perhaps the redefinition happened inside the script. Try to run `2 - 3`, *without* running `the-script` first. This should work now.
- This means that the change happened inside `the-script.jl`. Look for redefinitions of `-` inside that file.

If the above still doesn't work, the problem lies in some other library or script which is run. If so, try starting Julia like this:

```
 julia --startup-file=no
```

and then run `2 - 3` or something like that.

Comment: You are right. Could you help me identify where the redefinition is occurring. I tried breaking the `-` function again. I have pasted my code above in the question.

Comment: ok I found the error. I had a `-` sign in a variable name by accident.

Comment: It's probably the line `num_sp-meta = 10;` and now I'm super-curious how this typo can so easily re-defined `-` ... can a Julia expert explain that?

Comment: I guess the answer is that I pranked myself into losing an entire afternoon.....

Comment: Oh, yes, that's it. This is caused by a feature which is both cool and a bit dangerous. See here for a discussion: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15483 , and also here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/redefining-x-y-0/17015